Make Lua print more precise errors in non-interactive mode
This is a similar problem to that in this question but the solution there does not always work well enough. With -lua=batchmode.lua which takes into account the Lua script below, this
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\(\nonexisting\)
\end{document}

will produce ! Undefined control sequence. Without a line number but that's ok. This, however
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{nonexisting}

will produce ! Emergency stop which says nothing about the error. Can the configuration file batchmode.lua from the mentioned question
texconfig.interaction = 0 -- Activate batchmode
texconfig.halt_on_error = true -- Stop at first error

callback.register('show_error_message', function(...)
  texio.write_nl('term and log', status.lasterrorstring)
  texio.write('term', '.\n')
end)
callback.register('show_lua_error_hook', function(...)
  texio.write_nl('term and log', status.lastluaerrorstring)
  texio.write('term', '.\n')
end)

be modified to give more verbose error messages to its stdout or stderr? Not necessarily as verbose as in the interactive mode.

unrelated to the question but avoid using \RequirePackage{luatex85} is is only needed for temporary workarounds for packages that were never updated to work with luatex 1.0 and need the old luatex 0.85 interfaces. By now there should be almost none of those packages left.

I do not understand your initial comment will produce ! Undefined control sequence. Without a line number but that's ok  If I run your example with lualatex --interaction=batchmode there is no error message at all on the terminal but the log has the line number: ! Undefined control sequence. l.5 \(\nonexisting

@DavidCarlisle I use -lua=batchmode.lua. I updated the question to reflect that.

It's just an alternative way of entering batch mode, I don't think it changes my answer (but I'll check)

as expected, using that config is the same as I showed using --interaction=batchmode:  the first example gives a undefined control sequence  on line 5 error and the second gives either an emergency stop or missing file error depending on how the document file ends.

I do not understand your initial comment

will produce ! Undefined control sequence. Without a line number but that's ok

If I run your example with lualatex --interaction=batchmode (or equivalently using the supplied lua configuration) there is no error message at all on the terminal but the log has the line number: ! Undefined control sequence. l.5 \(\nonexisting
For the second example the behaviour (which is the same in classic tex) depends on how you end the file.
If you just have a single newline (or no newline) after \end{document} you get a log of
! Emergency stop.
<*> aa673
      
*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)

as latex was looking ahead for the optional argument to \documentclass and ran off the end of the file.
If you have two ends of lines at the end of the file, you get
! LaTeX Error: File `nonexisting.cls' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 
   
l.3 

with a missing file reported on line 3, as now latex detected there was no optional argument and so attempted (and failed) to input the class file.
So it is not that you have a missing file error that is not reported, no file input was attempted, and in fact no error was detected at all other than the fact that the file ended, so no legal \end found is the full information TeX has available.
